# File csv has "ñ" in headers, I can't read it with pandas

Tags: pandas, csv, unicode, utf-8, decode

I'm trying read csv with pandas, it has a header "año"

This is the unicode error

```
 UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd1 in position 1: invalid  continuation byte
```

How can I read this csv file? I have a lot of files with this problem.

Comment: Can you paste your code?

Answer (score 1):

It is not in UTF-8 format.  You need to give the format ISO-8859-1 to pandas.

You should post the pandas code where it's specifying UTF-8